# How to find out addresses of the slots in dynamically allocated multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I created a 2-dimensional dynamically allocated array. Then I wanted to output the addresses of the slots, so I can really see it's not a contiguous block of memory. I've managed to do that by `&tda[i][j]`  statement. However, I'm wondering how I could do that by using something like `*(tda+1)`, which is the same as `&tda[1][0]`. For example, how could I output `tda[1][1]` address using a combination of `*(tda+1)`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int **tda;
   tda = new int*[2];

   cout << tda << endl;
   cout << tda+1 << endl;

   for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
       tda[i] = new int[2];
   }

   cout << *(tda+1) << endl;

   cout << endl << "Proof that the block of memory is not contiguous:" << endl;
   for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
       for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
            cout << &tda[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you already mentioned the equivalence of `a[k]` and `*(a + k)`, but let me spell it out for you:

```
&tda[i][j]
```

is

```
&*(tda[i] + j)
```

is

```
*(tda + i) + j
```

Analogously,

```
tda[i][j]
```

becomes

```
*(*(tda + i) + j)
```